# Are content-available and alert mutually exclusive keys in an APNS aps dictionary

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The iOS app I'm working on uses push notifications to deliver messages the user can view in a Message Center. These messages have a set of custom keys outside the aps dictionary that we use to provide different treatments, etc. However, if the user doesn't tap on the notification, the message never appears in the app (server-side messaging not available yet).

So we started adding `content-available` to the aps dictionary so the app can consume the payload and prepare the message in the message center: the device still receives the notification but now the message is available if they open the app without tapping on the notification. This has been working great in practice.

It looks like this was supported in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) (Configuring a Background Update Notification section, now archived) but now [current docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app) say "*To send a background notification, create a remote notification with an aps dictionary that includes only the content-available key.... You may include custom keys in the payload, but the aps dictionary must not contain any keys that would trigger user interactions.*" And the [documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification) that leads to that says about `content-available`, "*The background notification flag. To perform a silent background update, specify the value 1 and don't include the alert, badge, or sound keys in your payload.*"

I guess what we're trying to do you could call a Noisy Background Notification, one that updates the app in the background and still has user facing/interactive content.

Are `content-available` and `alert` mutually exclusive keys in the `aps` dictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that the intent is to make these mutually exclusive. For example, see: 
https://onesignal.com/blog/ios-13-introduces-4-breaking-changes-to-notifications/

and/or research new apns-push-type header which must either be "alert" or "background".

Have you considered using the background mode to process what you need in the background and while doing that, have your app code create a UserNotification based upon the same payload that can be delivered to the device locally to also get the user-visible alert?

Comment: Thanks, I have read the OneSignal post and interpreted it a bit differently based on: "... Other documentation pages indicate that content-available can be set to 1 and apns-priority can still be set to 10, as long as the push message has content to be shown to the user (via the alert field of the APNS payload). Our findings are that the latter is true: At this time, apns-priorty only needs to be set to 5 for notifications without any alert data." continued...

Comment: That indicated to me that `content-available:1` is acceptable with an `alert` object in the aps dictionary and that `apns-priority:5` only needs to be set (`10` otherwise) when there is no `alert` object in the aps dict.

Comment: A Service Extension may be what we need to do to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: @soob I agree with your interpretation too, however I don't think it is forward-looking. The new apns-push-type header makes it appear that once this is mandatory it will be an either-or approach; at least, I wouldn't bank on it supporting both unless Apple becomes clearer about their intention to do so.

Comment: @bato, As per the Apple's User notifications docs, the background notifications are defined with `apns-push-type: background` and `apns-priority: 5` headers. `payload.aps` should only have `content-available: 1`. Background notifications are throttled if they are very frequent. Will my remote notifications with `apns-push-type: alert` and `apns-priority: 10` with `alert` and `content-available: 1` fields set, be also throttled?